# Single make rule for multiple output files in different directories

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Lets say I have one directory with c files (`.`) and I want the object files to end up in two different directories: debug and release. Now I want to make the rule for this. This will end up being something like this:

```
$(DEBUGDIR)%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(RELEASEDIR)%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

These are two rules which are exactly the same. Since all possible differences between those rules are contained in `CFLAGS` there is no reason to even have two rules: I want to maintain only one. I tried this:

```
$(DEBUGDIR)%.o $(RELEASEDIR)%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

But now it will not compile the o-files for `RELEASE` when it already compiled for `DEBUG`. How can I merge these two rules into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it.  Pattern rules with multiple targets [define a recipe that creates multiple output files when run one time](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html).

For this I'd just write the rule twice.  Alternatively you can put the recipe into a variable and use it twice:

```
COMPILE = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(DEBUGDIR)%.o : %.c
        $(COMPILE)

$(RELEASEDIR)%.o : %.c
        $(COMPILE)
```